# Discounted-cash-flow-analysis: Is it possible to calculate the the flow of cash given a certain fixed net present value?

Tags: programming, present-value

Is it possible to calculate the flow of cash in each period given a certain fixed net present value?

I would like to be able to apply a certain weighting that can be applied to the cash flows of each period e.g. 90% will be paid back in the last period, 1/(number of periods-1) in all other preceding periods.

For example, parameters could be:
number of periods of the cash flow, discount rate, indexation/inflation, certain weighting that can be applied to the cash flows of each period, etc.

What formula should I start from? Or is there a R/Python/... package that can calculate this for me?

[image]

So I want to calculate the uneven cash flows CF 1-n, which has to be done numerically I guess.

he thing is that I also need to calculate net present value, not just present value. So e.g. in the initial period there is a negative value of e.g. -100, and at the end it is assumed it can be resold for e.g. +95. Or based on some formula that relates the 100 to the 95 which can be complex. And all the in between cash flows are dependent on the 100 too, e.g. if they were discounted; they would each equal 1/(number of periods-2) of the initial cashflow

Comment: What about an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity ?

Comment: @Kermittfrog Annuity are equal payments per period I think? I need to be able to set a kind of weighting over periods: e.g. 90% will be paid back in the last period, 1/(number of periods-1) in all other periods.

Comment: On your wiki page, net present value is calculated from annuities. But I want to do the reverse: calculate the cash flows from a certain net present value and some parameters that need to be known (number of periods, ...).

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to hint at: you can calculate the cash flow given **all** other inputs.

Comment: Seems so indeed. But not with the weights included, can I? You can reformulate the formula when the dependencies between each cash flow are simple, e.g. each cash flow is 4% more than the year before. But not when the weights are something like [0.2 .01 0.4 0.3] maybe? Or at least I'm not able too reformulate the formula so looking for a software package/library that can do this for me.

Comment: The thing is that I also need to calculate net present value, not just present value. So e.g. in the initial period there is a negative value of e.g. -100, and at the end it is assumed it can be resold for e.g. +95. Or based on some formula that relates the 100 to the 95 which can be complex. And all the in between cash flows are dependent on the 100 too, e.g. if they were discounted; they would each equal 1/(number of periods-2) of the initial cashflow .